# Issue Annotating Points With Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, stock

I’m working on a Jupyter notebook script using Python and Matplotlib which is supposed to fetch historical stock prices for specified stocks via the `yfinance` package and plot each stock’s volatility vs. potential return.

The expected and actual results can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uyz6z.jpg).

As you can see in the second image, the annotations beside each point for the stock symbols are completely missing. I’m very new to Matplotlib, so I’m at a bit of a loss. The code being used is as follows:

```
import yfinance as yf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from functools import reduce
from google.colab import files

sns.set()

directory = '/datasets/stocks/'
stocks = ['AAPL', 'MSFT', 'AMD', 'TWTR', 'TSLA']

#Download each stock's 6-month historical daily stock price and save to a .csv
df_list = list()
for ticker in stocks:
    data = yf.download(ticker, group_by="Ticker", period='6mo')
    df = pd.concat([data])
    csv = df.to_csv()
    with open(directory+ticker+'.csv', 'w') as f:
      f.write(csv)

#Get the .csv filename as well as the full path to each file
ori_name = []
for stock in stocks:
  ori_name.append(stock + '.csv')
stocks = [directory + s for s in ori_name]

dfs = [pd.read_csv(s)[['Date', 'Close']] for s in stocks]
data = reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on='Date'), dfs).iloc[:, 1:]

returns = data.pct_change()
mean_daily_returns = returns.mean()
volatilities = returns.std()

combine = pd.DataFrame({'returns': mean_daily_returns * 252,
                       'volatility': volatilities * 252})

g = sns.jointplot("volatility", "returns", data=combine, kind="reg",height=7)

#Apply Annotations
for i in range(combine.shape[0]):
    name = ori_name[i].replace(',csv', '')
    x = combine.iloc[i, 1]
    y = combine.iloc[i, 0]
    print(name)
    print(x, y)
    print('\n')
    plt.annotate(name, xy=(x,y)) 
    
plt.show()
```

Printing out the stock name and the respective x,y position I am trying to place the annotation at shows the following:

```
AAPL.csv
4.285630458382526 0.24836925418906455


MSFT.csv
3.3916453932738966 0.5159276490876817


AMD.csv
6.040090684498841 -0.002179408770566866


TWTR.csv
7.911518867192316 0.8556785016280568


TSLA.csv
9.154424353004579 -0.40596099327336554
```

Unless I am mistaken, these are the exact points that are being plotted on the graph. As such, I am confused as to why the text isn’t being correctly annotated. I would assume it has something to do with the `xycoords` argument for `plt.annotate()`, but I don’t know enough about the different coordinate systems to know which one to use or whether that’s even the root cause of the issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I'm not an expert on `sns.jointplot`, but it has three subplots, so `plt.annotate` doesn't know which of the three to put the annotations in.  Dig into the docs and you should find a handle to the central axes in the `g` returned from `jointplot`, and then you can do `g.ax.annotate()`

Comment: @JodyKlymak Wow that was surprisingly simple and worked like a charm. Huge thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As @JodyKlymak stated in his comment above, the issue with my code stems from jointplot containing several subplots, preventing `annotate()` from knowing which axes to base the text placement off of. This was easily fixed by simply replacing `plt.annotate()` with `g.ax_joint.annotate()`.